# npm registry old package version using Azure Artifacts

Tags: angular, azure, npm, npm-install, azure-artifacts

I have a private NPM registry that seems to refuse to update latest version of specific pacakages, even tho the module of the specific version is shown in the registry (Azure Artifacts).
When I try to download the package from Azure Artifacts website, I get following error message:

```
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1302.2.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of '@angular-devkit/build-angular'
npm ERR! notarget
```

Following command:

> npm view @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1302.2

Is showing the previous version

```
dist-tags:
latest: 0.1302.1
```

Even tho the 0.1302.2 is shown in the Azure Artifact page, and I can download the package manually from the web page.

npm cache clear and delete node_modules has no effect, as it seems to be the registry that is somehow corrupted. Is there any way to force update the registry, to make sure it has detected the newest versions of my NPM packages using Azure Artifacts as NPM registry??

UPDATE:
I forgot to mention that when I skip my private registry and pointing towards the default public  registry, then *npm i* runs without any issues.